# Delphi convert Currency

Tags: delphi, currency

Hi I would like to covert a certain currency to another, like say from USD to EUR but also any other currency, I have no idea how to do this, can someone please help me?

Comment: Simply multiply the value by the exchange rate. The current exchange rate for USD/EUR is 0.86. So 1 USD is 0.86 EUR, 5 USD is 4.30 EUR, etc

Answer (score 2):

You can easily use the following method as guide:

```
function EuroToDollar(amount: integer): double;
begin
  Result := amount * 1.17;
end;
```

I have taken `1.17` from Google but you can find conversion rates easily everywhere.

---

That approach is good but not flexible because you should create a lot of functions if you consider that there are many currencies. I have created this simple VCL application:

```
type
  TCurrency = (cEuro, cDollar, cWhatever);
  TConversion = reference to function(target: TCurrency; amount: double): double;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    CurrencyList: TDictionary<TCurrency, TConversion>;
  public
    function Convert(fromCurr: TCurrency; toCurr: TCurrency; amount: double): double;
  end;
```

I use a dictionary to store the currency and the conversion method that you have to use.

```
//example
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  euro, dollar: double;
begin
  //euro-dollar
  euro := Convert(cEuro, cDollar, 2);
  ShowMessage(euro.ToString);

  //dollar-euro
  dollar := Convert(cDollar, cEuro, 5);
  ShowMessage(dollar.ToString);
end;

function TForm1.Convert(fromCurr, toCurr: TCurrency; amount: double): double;
begin
  Result := CurrencyList[fromCurr](toCurr, amount);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CurrencyList := TDictionary<TCurrency, TConversion>.Create();

  CurrencyList.Add(TCurrency.cEuro, function(target: TCurrency; amount: double): double
                                    begin
                                      case target of
                                        cDollar:
                                          begin
                                            Result := amount * 1.17;
                                          end;
                                      end;
                                    end);

  CurrencyList.Add(TCurrency.cDollar, function(target: TCurrency; amount: double): double
                                      begin
                                        case target of
                                          cEuro:
                                            begin
                                              Result := amount * 0.86;
                                            end;
                                        end;
                                      end);
end;
```

In this way you once define a currency and then you can add conversions simply by adding new values in the `case`. This is a skeleton of what I think you could do but there could be more (like getting the conversion constants from a website) but that goes beyond the scope of the answer.

Comment: Thanks but is there anyway I can get up to date exchange rates, I am writing a program for a friend that basically shows his stock and sales, and buys his stock online using other currencys, he wants it to convert their currencys to whatever currency he chooses, is there a way maybe that I can do that?

Comment: Of course there is, but I cannot make the program for you. Instead I could give a suggestion! Use my code; then use Indy and IdHTTP to execute GET requests and get the conversion constants (0.86, 1.17...) in json format or whatever. Finally fill the dictionary with every currency and every conversion.

Comment: My comment above tells you how you could do it but that's a lot of work and it's not actually so easy. It would be better if you changed your strategy completely: use online APIs to convert currencies (and with IdHTTP get the result) or use a database (like sql) to store the conversion rates and query it. These approaches would probably make more sense

Comment: @E.T How to convert currency by exchange rate and how to obtain exchange rate are *two entirely different unrelated things*.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it, will give it a try